# Error redirecting to page in ASP.NET Core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to redirect to this page
[root that I want to redirect to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osW9h.png),

[image]

but I got this error :

> InvalidOperationException: No page named 'Miner/MinerDetail' matches the supplied values.

I want to redirect to this page `miner/MinerDetail` with a model that it is `minerPartsView`

Comment: How's your `MinerDetails` looks like? Did your tried with out the parameter I mean without partial view data?

Comment: yes i tried , i actully tried to partial view not page . so i change to page

Comment: Thanks for your response, I hope it helped to reesolve your issue on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Want to redirect to this page miner/MinerDetail with a model that it
> is minerPartsView

Well, as per your shared screenshot, it appeared that, you were not able to redirect to your `MinerDetails page` due to two main reason.

Firstly, if your `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` executes then your next block will not executes, you have already returned the statements.

Second, reason you are not redirecting to the `MinerDetails page` in correct manner. As you haven't share your `MinerDetails page` details design thus I am sharing how you could redirect to a new `razorpage` with new object.

**Model:**

Let's assume, we have below model which we would like to pass from our intial page to `MinerDetails page`.

```
public class MinerCustomModel
    {

        public string? PowerSerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string? MinerSerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string? WorkerName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** In your scenario, model would be `minerPartsView` model

**Intial Index/ Loading Page:**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
       
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {
            var myData = new MinerCustomModel()
            {
                MinerSerialNumber = "SM-001",
                PowerSerialNumber = "PSN-002",
                WorkerName = "Worker Name"
            };

            string data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(myData);
            return RedirectToPage("Miner/MinerDetails", new  { objectData = data });

           
        }
    }
```

**MinerDetails Page:**

```
public class MinerDetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public MinerCustomModel? minerCustomModel { get; set; } = new MinerCustomModel();

       
        public void OnGet(string objectData)
        {
            
            var enitity = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MinerCustomModel>(objectData);

            minerCustomModel.PowerSerialNumber = enitity.PowerSerialNumber;
            minerCustomModel.MinerSerialNumber = enitity.MinerSerialNumber;
            minerCustomModel.WorkerName = enitity.WorkerName;
           
         
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Make sure, we are defining the `MinerCustomModel` which should a `class` not `pageModel`  with `[BindProperty]` which should intializing as `new MinerCustomModel()` to avoid null reference exception.

**MinerDetailsModel Page View:**

```
@page
@model MinerDetailsModel


<h1>Miner Details</h1>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                PowerSerialNumber
            </th>
            <th>
                MinerSerialNumber
            </th>
            <th>
                WorkerName
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       
            <tr>
                <td>
                @Model.minerCustomModel?.PowerSerialNumber
                </td>
                <td>
                @Model.minerCustomModel?.MinerSerialNumber
                </td>
                <td>
                @Model.minerCustomModel?.WorkerName
                </td>
            </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:**  In MinerDetails view we should refer `@model MinerDetailsModel page model` not the `MinerCustomModel` or `IndexModel`.

**Output:**

[image]